# How to know if CURL return true or false?

Tags: php, curl, telegram, telegram-bot

Previous i had the problem to print content body from http request using `CURL` and i solved adding this:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

but now if i `print_r(curl_exec($ch))` i have only the body and not **true** or **false**.

I have this structure in content body:

```
ok: true
    result: 
        message_id: 12186
        from:   
            id: 12345678
            is_bot: true
            first_name: "bot"
            username:   "my bot"
        chat:   
            id: 12345
            first_name: "Gio"
            last_name:  "Bor"
            username:   "giobor"
            type:   "private"
        date:   1571676256
        text:   "okk"
```

So how can i have both togheter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`curl_errno()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) in order to determine whether or not an error occurred. If the return value is `0` then the request succeeded, otherwise there was an error. Additionally, use [`curl_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to receive a string containing the corresponding error message for debugging purposes.